# Over-ride styling for Material-UI Tag

Tags: material-ui

I was unable to over ride the styling for Material UI's Tabs in React. I used the component  wanted to override it's indicator color, text color but failed.

I already tried adding a new className to override the values but failed. event I switch the indicator color and text color to none, it only switch back to the default setting.

```
    <Tabs value={TabValue} className={classes.tabs}
      indicatorColor="primary"
      textColor="primary"
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
```

I expect the .tabs will change the value of my indicator and text color but nothing happens

Hope someone can enlighten me on this!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Tabs docs](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/):
indicatorColor can be one of: '*primary*', '*secondary*'. default is '*secondary*' 
textColor can be one of: '*primary*', '*secondary*', '*inherit*'. default is '*inherit* 
In the following example, I change (not override) the default textColor and indicatorColor:

```
  <AppBar position="static">
    <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange}
     indicatorColor="primary" //default is secondary
     textColor="secondary"  //default is inherit
    >
      <Tab label="Item One" />
      <Tab label="Item Two"  />
      <Tab label="Item Three" />
    </Tabs>
  </AppBar>
```

If you want to **override** the primary and secondary colors, use MuiTheme:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import {green, blue} from '@material-ui/core/colors';

const theme = createMuiTheme({ 
  palette: { // i override the default palette
    primary: green,
    secondary: blue
  }
});
```

And than wrap your component with ThemeProvider:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} indicatorColor="secondary">
        <Tab label="Item One" />
        <Tab label="Item Two"  />
        <Tab label="Item Three" />
      </Tabs>
    </AppBar>  
</ThemeProvider>
```

You can refer to this CodeSandbox working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-49mym?fontsize=14

Comment: Hi Ido,
Thanks for the help,

I tried :
const theme = createMuiTheme({ 
  palette: {
    primary: {
        main: '#456345',
},
    secondary: {
      main:'#256728'
}
  }
});
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} 
              indicatorColor="secondary">
        <Tab label="Item One" />
        <Tab label="Item Two"  />
        <Tab label="Item Three" />
      </Tabs>
</ThemeProvider>

it didn't work